# For mobile app updates why does the entire app need to be downloaded again?

Tags: mobile

I have noticed on a number of platforms: iOS, Android and BlackBerry that when updating an app the entire app is downloaded again (others mobile platforms may work this way too but I have only been exposed to these platforms).

**Why does the entire app need to be downloaded again for an update instead of incremental updates?**

This seems very inefficient especially if you are dealing with large apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic question is not true for iOS, [as of 6.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1779/_index.html):

> Starting with iOS 6, the app store will automatically produce an
>   update package for all new versions of apps submitted to the store.
>   This package is optimized for updating an app from one version to
>   another, and contains files that have changed between the prior
>   version of an app and the new version of the app, excluding files that
>   have not changed.
>
> When used optimally, an update package is significantly smaller to
>   download than the full package of the app and the update will install
>   more quickly. Also, in many cases, this mechanism allows updates to
>   large apps to be downloadable over cellular networks where app
>   downloads are subject to a size limit.
>
> In addition to new content, the update package contains instructions
>   on how to transform the prior version of the app into the new version
>   of the app. New files will be added, modified files will be replaced
>   with their updated counterpart, and deleted files will be removed as
>   part of this transformation. As far as the developer and user are
>   concerned, this process is entirely transparent and the resulting
>   updated app will be indistinguishable from a full download of the
>   corresponding updated version of their app.

So, yes, it is possible to do delta application updates, as well as delta OS updates, on mobile platforms. This capability simply has to be added by the OS vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the code and other content might be updated and/or changed. This requires a update. Since Android does not allow you to change/delete/add files to the installation folder, you have to download and reinstall the whole app.

Comment: Neither does any other os